# Firefox : override website's JavaScript to a local machine JavaScript

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, plugins, greasemonkey

There is a `userContent.css` available in Firefox to customize / override a website's CSS to a new one, but what about the JavaScript?

How can I override a particular website's JavaScript or some part of the JavaScript of a website to a local machine's JavaScript in Firefox?

Any greasemonkey tips or something else native tips without any addons? or are there any plugins available for the same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, tested with Firefox 115.

Open the debugger, select the file you'd like to override, right click and select "Add script override".

[image: Screenshot of the "Add script override" button in the dev tools]

Select a destination for the file, and click save. You can now edit the file (for example, to add `console.log('override!!')` at the top) and the new file will be used when you reload:

[image: showing 'override!!' in console]

There will be a little purple dot in the debugger indicating its overridden state:

[image: purple dot indicating override]

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to override the original JavaScript functionality of a website in some cases. I know of examples using bookmarklets:

- [HOW TO turn off copy-pasting restrictions on web form fields of annoying websites](https://mvark.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-turn-off-copy-pasting.html)
- [StopTabAlerts - a bookmarklet to replace dynamic blinking alerts in tab with custom text](https://mvark.blogspot.com/2014/07/stoptabalerts-bookmarklet-to-replace.html)